# Can I use & operator to get a valid pointer in a function even if the function has returned in golang

Tags: c, pointers, go

some code as below

```
type TUser struct {
    Name    string
    Addr    string
}

var UserMap map[int]*TUser  //save TUser pointer to map

func LoadUsers() {

    ... ...
    //assume "row" contains the results of table "users" from db
    UserMap[0] = &TUser{Name:row["name"], Addr:row["addr"]}
}
```

My question is:
After the function "LoadUsers" returns, is the pointer in "UserMap[0]" valid?
or it would become a wild pointer like we do the same thing in C language?

Thanks

Comment: Go is memory-safe, and never has dangling pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly valid

From [the FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap):

> **How do I know whether a variable is allocated on the heap or the stack?**
>
> From a correctness standpoint, you don't need to know. **Each variable
>   in Go exists as long as there are references to it**. The storage
>   location chosen by the implementation is irrelevant to the semantics
>   of the language.
>
> The storage location does have an effect on writing efficient
>   programs. When possible, the Go compilers will allocate variables that
>   are local to a function in that function's stack frame. However, if
>   the compiler cannot prove that the variable is not referenced after
>   the function returns, then the compiler must allocate the variable on
>   the garbage-collected heap to avoid dangling pointer errors. Also, if
>   a local variable is very large, it might make more sense to store it
>   on the heap rather than the stack.
>
> In the current compilers, if a variable has its address taken, that
>   variable is a candidate for allocation on the heap. However, a basic
>   escape analysis recognizes some cases when such variables will not
>   live past the return from the function and can reside on the stack.